# Group by with count on multiple table in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

Sql query to LINQ: Both are pasted over here, getting issue in LINQ - need suggestion:

```
select bm.MachineId,al.AlarmId,am.AlarmName, count(al.AlarmId)AlarmCount 
from BatchMachineWise bm 
join AlarmLog al on bm.MachineId = al.MachineId
join Alarm am on am.AlarmId = al.AlarmId
where bm.BatchId = 12476
group by bm.MachineId,al.AlarmId,am.AlarmName
```

[image: sql o/p]

[image: LINQ query]

[image: getting the error]

Comment: `gr.Key.MachineId` `gr.Key.AlarmId` `gr.Key.AlarmName`?

Comment: Also please do not post code and errors as images cause they are basically text.

Answer (score 2):

`GroupBy` returns [`IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-5.0) interface which has [`Key` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2.key?view=net-5.0) which should be used to access fields used for grouping:

```
select new AlarmSummary
{
    MachineId = gr.Key.MachineId,
    AlarmId = gr.Key.AlarmId, 
    AlarmName = gr.Key.AlarmName
    ....
}
```

Comment: @user10181000 was glad to help!